# When converting strptime to as.POSIXct, the millisecond changes

Tags: strptime, milliseconds

I have a strptime objective as follows:

```
a<-strptime(time_second, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
head(a)
[1] "2016-07-05 20:53:47.166 CDT" "2016-07-05 21:45:00.485 GMT"
[3] "2016-07-05 21:45:30.031 CDT" "2016-07-05 21:45:52.106 GMT"
[5] "2016-07-05 21:45:52.106 CDT" "2016-07-05 21:45:52.106 GMT"
```

When I convert it by using as.POSIT I got follows:

```
b<-as.POSIXct(a)
head(b)
[1] "2016-07-05 20:53:47.165 GMT" "2016-07-05 21:45:00.484 GMT"
[3] "2016-07-05 21:45:30.030 GMT" "2016-07-05 21:45:52.105 GMT"
[5] "2016-07-05 21:45:52.105 GMT" "2016-07-05 21:45:52.106 GMT"
```

You find some millisecond reduced by 1 ms, some does not change (e.g. the last one). Can anyone figure out what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `some does not change (e.g. the last one)` - I can't see a difference in "decrement" between the lines prefixed `[1]` and `[3]` and the one prefixed `[5]`.)

Comment: you haven't said which programming language you're using.

Comment: Sorry. I use R.